# Tailwind + Vite not working correctly. [plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Cannot create property

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

Using Filament with laravel
Trying to override colors in theme

But even I'm doing same as docs
it showing error like that
[image]